# HashSet in Apache Freemarker for fast lookup

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker, hashset

I have the following code that performs a filter (do not insert duplicates) in Apache Freemarker. To do so, I make use of a list as follows:

```java
<#assign newList = [] />
<#list instructions as instruction>
<#if ! newList?seq_contains(instruction.opCode)>
<#assign newList = newList + [instruction.opCode] />
            case ${instruction.opCode?string.computer}: instruction = create${instruction.name}(line, scope); break;
</#if>
</#list>
```

Since the list is actually large (contains a few thousand items), it takes a while. I would like to speed up the process by using a HashSet instead. However, I can't find the right methods to do that. When I transform the list to a hashMap `<#assign newList = {} />` then I cannot query using the `containsKey` or similar methods, but rather `keys` and `values`.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this purely in the template (with reasonable performance and readability), as the template language doesn't support modifiable collections. You are supposed to do such data processing in Java. Ideally, the data-model (template context) already contains the data processed. But alternatively, you can expose some Java utilities to the template and call those from the template to do this.

Comment: Can you expand on the Java utilities to the template? Any reference?

Comment: @snatverk If you can add objects to the data-model (or if you can configure FreeMarker you can even add "shared variables" to the shared `Configuration`), then it's just any Java object with public class, and you can call its public methods. It's also possible to use a static utility class, if you search for `getStaticModels`. If you can't add to the data-model or configure... there's `?new` with witch you can instantiate your class if it implements `TemplateModel` (and see its subclasses), but therefore you need to be able to add a new Java class to the application.

Comment: I finally solved it in another way. For my case, I took advantage that the input list was already sorted, so I can only check repeated values by checking the first or last element of the list. This solves my issue. The compilation was down from 3 mins to 4 seconds ! Thank you for the advice. It helped me to understand better the Freemarker Framework.